# How to slicing data and create new columns referencing other columns value to pivot in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, filtering

I am working on a survey and the data looks like this:

```
ID    Q1    Q2    Q3    Gender    Age    Dep    Ethnicity
001   Y      N    Y      M         22     IT        W
002   N      Y    Y      M         35     HR        W
003   Y      N    N      M         20     IT        A
004   Y      N    Y      M         54     OPRE      B
005   Y      N    Y      M         42     OPRE      B
```

Now, I'd like to add group ethnicity and Gender to create a table like:

```
Question  Dep   Response  #White Man   #Diverse Man    %White Man  %Diverse Man 
 Q1     IT        Y        1               1           50           50
        IT        N        0               0            0            0
        HR        Y        0               0            0            0
        HR        N        1               0            100          0 
        OPRE      Y        0               2            0          100
        OPRE      N        0               0            0            0  
 Q2     IT        Y        0               0            0            0
        IT        N        1               1           50           50
        HR        Y        1               0            100          0
        HR        N        0               0            0            0 
        OPRE      Y        0               0            0            0
        OPRE      N        0               2            0            0
 Q3 ......
```

My codes are like this:

```
df['White Man'] = df[df[Gender] == 'Man']&df[Ethnicity] = 'White']
```

But I don't know if there is a Contains function in Python or not. What I did above is only filtering, it will not add 1 in the results.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the most efficient way of solving your problem, but it solves it as far as I can see

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Q1': ['Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'],
    'Q2': ['N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N'],
    'Q3': ['Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y'],
    'Gender': ['M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M'],
    'Age': [22, 35, 20, 54, 42],
    'Dep': ['IT', 'HR', 'IT', 'OPRE', 'OPRE'],
    'Ethnicity': ['W', 'W', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    })

df = pd.melt(df, id_vars = ['Gender', 'Age', 'Dep', 'Ethnicity'],
       value_vars=['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3'],
       var_name='Question',
       value_name='Answer')

df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Question', 'Dep','Answer', 'Ethnicity'], aggfunc='count')['Age']

df = df.unstack(level=3).reset_index()
df = df.fillna(0)
```

At least from here it should be easy for you to fully reach what you want